# Plotting lubridate periods using R

Tags: r, time, plot, lubridate

I have a series of lengths of time expressed as strings, e.g., 3:15, for 3 mins 15 secs. I have read these in and converted to periods using Lubridate, e.g.,

```
library(lubridate)
times <- ms(c("3:15","5:13","4:21","3:14","5:50"))
```

How can I plot these as a histogram, with the x-axis in some kind of minute:second format? Using simply `hist(times)` gives me the numeric value of the periods (as if they were plotted with `as.numeric`), which doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Plotting `hist(as.period(times))` produces the same result.

Answer (score 3):

After applying the function `ms` on `times` you transformed it from a vector to an object like this:

```
> class(times)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
```

You can use `times@` to see what info you can get from that object.

Maybe `hist(times@minute)` is better for you. Also, try some variation by manually choosing `breaks` like : `hist(times@minute, breaks=20)`

Comment: I see. So Lubridate in this instance probably is not very useful, I'd be better off converting to seconds or a numeric fraction of a minute.

Comment: Exactly. You loose some info from the seconds here. Also, 3.15 on the x-axis is not 3:15, as x axis includes values like 3.70 etc. I'd use seconds for each Min:Sec value, plot using seconds and use Min:Sec as labels on the x-axis (just for visualisation) maybe using ggplot (?).